# Save as on multiple files at once (GIMP)

Tags: image, png, gimp, xcf

I have a series of *.xcf* images which I want to save as *.png*. I can open each file and save as *.png* but since there are a lot of images it would take a fair amount of time.

Is there a way to convert all images at once, or another way I have to spent less time on this job?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you have `imagemagick` installed, you can do it like:

```
mogrify -format png *.xcf
```

This converts them automatically in the same directory. Also read `man mogrify` [or this](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/mogrify.html) for other options.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the Python console inside GIMP for that - if you happen to be in Windows, take a look on how to install the Python extension for GIMP 2.6 (on Linux it either comes isntalled or is a matter of installing the gimp-python package, probably the same on Mac OS)

From within GIMP's Python console you have access to a huge GIMP API you can check by looking at the help->Procedure Browser dialog - besides having all the other features of Python, including file and strign manipulation.

One you are =in the Python-fu console, it is matter of doing something like this:

```
import glob
for fname in glob.glob("*.xcf"):
    img = pdb.gimp_file_load(fname, fname)
    img.flatten()
    new_name = fname[:-4] + ".png"
    pdb.gimp_file_save(img, img.layers[0], new_name, new_name)
```

(this will work on the directory GIMP uses as default - concatenate the desried directory to the filepaths to work on other dirs).

If you need to that more than once, take a look on the example plugins that come with gimp-Python, and paste the code above as the core fo a python plug-in for GIMP for your own use.

Comment: Being a batch conversion tool is not a core target for GIMP. That can be done through third party scripting, though, and yes , better support for a script eco-system is lacking.

Answer (score 2):

You can quickly create a plugin called SaveAll. Save this code to some file with .scm extension (e.g. saveall.scm):

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; 
; This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify 
; it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by 
; the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or 
; (at your option) any later version. 
; 
; This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, 
; but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of 
; MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the 
; GNU General Public License for more details. 

(define (script-fu-save-all-images) 
  (let* ((i (car (gimp-image-list))) 
         (image)) 
    (while (> i 0) 
      (set! image (vector-ref (cadr (gimp-image-list)) (- i 1))) 
      (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE 
                      image 
                      (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image)) 
                      (car (gimp-image-get-filename image)) 
                      (car (gimp-image-get-filename image))) 
      (gimp-image-clean-all image) 
      (set! i (- i 1))))) 

(script-fu-register "script-fu-save-all-images" 
 "<Image>/File/Save ALL" 
 "Save all opened images" 
 "Saul Goode" 
 "Saul Goode" 
 "11/21/2006" 
 "" 
 )
```

Put the file into plugins folder with same extension 
(on Windows it's C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\share\gimp\2.0\scripts).

Then you don't even have to restart the app. **Filters** menu -> **Script-Fu** -> **Update scripts**. You'll have **Save ALL** item in the **File** menu (at the very bottom). It works quick an easy for me.

This script come from [here](http://gimp.1065349.n5.nabble.com/Save-all-opened-files-with-ONE-click-or-with-script-td7820.html).

There's also [another](http://gimpscripts.com/2015/03/save-all/) script, but I haven't tested it myself.

Answer (score -2):

```
{
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; This program is free software; you 
; can redistribute it and/or modify 
; it under the terms of the GNU 
; General Public License as published 
; by the Free Software Foundation; 
; either version 2 of the License, or 
; (at your option) any later version. 
; 
; This program is distributed in the
; hope that it will be useful, 
; but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY;
; without even the implied warranty of 
; MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS 
; FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  
; See the GNU General Public License
;  for more details. 

(define (script-fu-save-all-images inDir inSaveType 
inFileName inFileNumber) 
  (let* (
          (i (car (gimp-image-list)))
          (ii (car (gimp-image-list))) 
          (image)
          (newFileName "")
          (saveString "")
          (pathchar (if (equal? 
                 (substring gimp-dir 0 1) "/") "/" "\\"))
        )
    (set! saveString
      (cond 
        (( equal? inSaveType 0 ) ".jpg" )
        (( equal? inSaveType 1 ) ".bmp" )
        (( equal? inSaveType 2 ) ".png" )
        (( equal? inSaveType 3 ) ".tif" )
      )
    ) 
    (while (> i 0) 
      (set! image (vector-ref (cadr (gimp-image-list)) (- i 1)))
      (set! newFileName (string-append inDir 
              pathchar inFileName 
              (substring "00000" (string-length 
              (number->string (+ inFileNumber i))))
              (number->string (+ inFileNumber i)) saveString))
      (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE 
                      image
                      (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image))
                      newFileName
                      newFileName
      ) 
      (gimp-image-clean-all image) 
      (set! i (- i 1))
    )
  )
) 

(script-fu-register "script-fu-save-all-images" 
 "<Image>/File/Save ALL As" 
 "Save all opened images as ..." 
 "Lauchlin Wilkinson (& Saul Goode)" 
 "Lauchlin Wilkinson (& Saul Goode)" 
 "2014/04/21" 
 ""
 SF-DIRNAME    "Save Directory" ""
 SF-OPTION     "Save File Type" (list "jpg" "bmp" "png" "tif")
 SF-STRING     "Save File Base Name" "IMAGE"
 SF-ADJUSTMENT "Save File Start Number" 
      (list 0 0 9000 1 100 0 SF-SPINNER)
 )

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a way and it requires no programming skills. Just install the free [Batch Image Manipulation Plugin](https://alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/) [[archive]](https://web.archive.org/web/20230929144637/https://alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/). The project is open source and it is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/alessandrofrancesconi/gimp-plugin-bimp).

Answer (score -3):

This script works perfectly in `gimp 2.8` Windows 7.

> UCHLIN WILKINSON SAVE ALL OPEN IMAGES FROM GIMP.

Handy if you are scanning in a lot of images and you just want to export them all in one go. It is based on a script by Saul Goode, extended to prompt for image base name, directory etc.

Save it as saveall.scm in your Gimp scripts directory. E.g. ~/.gimp-2.8/scripts/

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; This program is free software; you 
; can redistribute it and/or modify 
; it under the terms of the GNU 
; General Public License as published 
; by the Free Software Foundation; 
; either version 2 of the License, or 
; (at your option) any later version. 
; 
; This program is distributed in the
; hope that it will be useful, 
; but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY;
; without even the implied warranty of 
; MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS 
; FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  
; See the GNU General Public License
;  for more details. 

(define (script-fu-save-all-images inDir inSaveType 
inFileName inFileNumber) 
  (let* (
          (i (car (gimp-image-list)))
          (ii (car (gimp-image-list))) 
          (image)
          (newFileName "")
          (saveString "")
          (pathchar (if (equal? 
                 (substring gimp-dir 0 1) "/") "/" "\\"))
        )
    (set! saveString
      (cond 
        (( equal? inSaveType 0 ) ".jpg" )
        (( equal? inSaveType 1 ) ".bmp" )
        (( equal? inSaveType 2 ) ".png" )
        (( equal? inSaveType 3 ) ".tif" )
      )
    ) 
    (while (> i 0) 
      (set! image (vector-ref (cadr (gimp-image-list)) (- i 1)))
      (set! newFileName (string-append inDir 
              pathchar inFileName 
              (substring "00000" (string-length 
              (number->string (+ inFileNumber i))))
              (number->string (+ inFileNumber i)) saveString))
      (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE 
                      image
                      (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image))
                      newFileName
                      newFileName
      ) 
      (gimp-image-clean-all image) 
      (set! i (- i 1))
    )
  )
) 

(script-fu-register "script-fu-save-all-images" 
 "<Image>/File/Save ALL As" 
 "Save all opened images as ..." 
 "Lauchlin Wilkinson (& Saul Goode)" 
 "Lauchlin Wilkinson (& Saul Goode)" 
 "2014/04/21" 
 ""
 SF-DIRNAME    "Save Directory" ""
 SF-OPTION     "Save File Type" (list "jpg" "bmp" "png" "tif")
 SF-STRING     "Save File Base Name" "IMAGE"
 SF-ADJUSTMENT "Save File Start Number" 
      (list 0 0 9000 1 100 0 SF-SPINNER)
 )
```